# Convert an XML file into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I receive a delivery schedule from one of our customers and it is in XML format (they also send in Excel spreadsheet format so that it can be read by a human). I would like to run some SQL script that reads the schedule and appends the records to an SQL Server table. I can then easily compare it to data that is in our current ERP system.

From what I can figure out from the file itself (it looks like it's been auto created from a Crystal Report), it assigns each part number to a RowNumber and each week (0-11) as a column number. It then gives a 'cell value' (which is the quantity required) to a Row/Column reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CrystalReport xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd">
<ReportHeader>
</ReportHeader>
<Group Level="1">
<GroupHeader>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Text Name="Text4"><TextValue>DELIVERY SCHEDULE</TextValue>
</Text>
<Field Name="DataTime2" FieldName="DataTime"><FormattedValue>09:00:04</FormattedValue><Value>09:00:04</Value></Field>
<Field Name="DataDate2" FieldName="DataDate"><FormattedValue>10/02/2020</FormattedValue><Value>2020-02-10</Value></Field>
<Picture Name="Picture1" GraphicType="OLE">
</Picture>
<Text Name="Text13"><TextValue>DELIVERY ADDRESS</TextValue>
</Text>
<Text Name="Text8"><TextValue>SUPPLIER ADDRESS</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="1">
<Text Name="Text5"><TextValue>MyCompany
addressline1
addressline2
postcode

</TextValue>
</Text>
<Field Name="WHS2" FieldName="{@WHS}"><FormattedValue>Customer
Address1
Postcode
UK</FormattedValue><Value>customer
Customeraddreess
UK</Value></Field>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="2">
<Text Name="Text7"><TextValue>IMPORTANT

EACH ORDER REQUIRES A SEPERATE DELIVERY NOTE PER DELIVERY ADDRESS
</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
</GroupHeader>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<GroupFooter>
<Section SectionNumber="1">
<CrossTab Name="CrossTab2">
<RowGroups>
<RowGroup>
<RowGroup>
<RowTotal RowNumber="0">P10711</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="1">P10822</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="2">P10985</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="3">P11236</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="4">P12643</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="5">P13361</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="6">P14452</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="7">P16061</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="8">P16098</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="9">P16156</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="10">P16871</RowTotal>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroups>
<ColumnGroups>
<ColumnGroup>
<ColumnGroup>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="0"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="1"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="2"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="3"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="4"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="5"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="6"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="7"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="8"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="9"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="10"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="11"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="12"></ColumnTotal>
</ColumnGroup>
</ColumnGroup>
</ColumnGroups>
<Cells>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>60</FormattedValue><Value>60.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>100</FormattedValue><Value>100.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>50</FormattedValue><Value>50.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>40</FormattedValue><Value>40.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>100</FormattedValue><Value>100.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>30</FormattedValue><Value>30.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>30</FormattedValue><Value>30.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>30</FormattedValue><Value>30.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>30</FormattedValue><Value>30.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>30</FormattedValue><Value>30.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>30</FormattedValue><Value>30.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>30</FormattedValue><Value>30.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>30</FormattedValue><Value>30.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>300</FormattedValue><Value>300.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>300</FormattedValue><Value>300.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>300</FormattedValue><Value>300.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="12">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>10</FormattedValue><Value>10.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
</Cells>
</CrossTab>
</Section>
</GroupFooter>
</Group>
<Group Level="1">
<GroupHeader>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Text Name="Text4"><TextValue>DELIVERY SCHEDULE</TextValue>
</Text>
<Field Name="DataTime2" FieldName="DataTime"><FormattedValue>09:00:04</FormattedValue><Value>09:00:04</Value></Field>
<Field Name="DataDate2" FieldName="DataDate"><FormattedValue>10/02/2020</FormattedValue><Value>2020-02-10</Value></Field>
<Picture Name="Picture1" GraphicType="OLE">
</Picture>
<Text Name="Text13"><TextValue>DELIVERY ADDRESS</TextValue>
</Text>
<Text Name="Text8"><TextValue>SUPPLIER ADDRESS</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="1">
<Text Name="Text5"><TextValue>MyCompany
Address1
postcode

</TextValue>
</Text>
<Field Name="WHS2" FieldName="{@WHS}"><FormattedValue>Customer
address1
postcode
UK</FormattedValue><Value>Customer
address1
postcode
UK</Value></Field>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="2">
<Text Name="Text7"><TextValue>IMPORTANT

EACH ORDER REQUIRES A SEPERATE DELIVERY NOTE PER DELIVERY ADDRESS
</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
</GroupHeader>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<GroupFooter>
<Section SectionNumber="1">
<CrossTab Name="CrossTab2">
<RowGroups>
<RowGroup>
<RowGroup>
<RowTotal RowNumber="0">P22031</RowTotal>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroups>
<ColumnGroups>
<ColumnGroup>
<ColumnGroup>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="0"></ColumnTotal>
</ColumnGroup>
</ColumnGroup>
</ColumnGroups>
<Cells>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>4</FormattedValue><Value>4.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
</Cells>
</CrossTab>
</Section>
</GroupFooter>
</Group>
<Group Level="1">
<GroupHeader>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Text Name="Text4"><TextValue>DELIVERY SCHEDULE</TextValue>
</Text>
<Field Name="DataTime2" FieldName="DataTime"><FormattedValue>09:00:04</FormattedValue><Value>09:00:04</Value></Field>
<Field Name="DataDate2" FieldName="DataDate"><FormattedValue>10/02/2020</FormattedValue><Value>2020-02-10</Value></Field>
<Picture Name="Picture1" GraphicType="OLE">
</Picture>
<Text Name="Text13"><TextValue>DELIVERY ADDRESS</TextValue>
</Text>
<Text Name="Text8"><TextValue>SUPPLIER ADDRESS</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="1">
<Text Name="Text5"><TextValue>mycompany
address1
postcode

</TextValue>
</Text>
<Field Name="WHS2" FieldName="{@WHS}"><FormattedValue>customer
address1
postcode
UK</FormattedValue><Value>customer
address1
postcode
UK</Value></Field>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="2">
<Text Name="Text7"><TextValue>IMPORTANT

EACH ORDER REQUIRES A SEPERATE DELIVERY NOTE PER DELIVERY ADDRESS
</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
</GroupHeader>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<Group Level="2">
</Group>
<GroupFooter>
<Section SectionNumber="1">
<CrossTab Name="CrossTab2">
<RowGroups>
<RowGroup>
<RowGroup>
<RowTotal RowNumber="0">P24434</RowTotal>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroups>
<ColumnGroups>
<ColumnGroup>
<ColumnGroup>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="0"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="1"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="2"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="3"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="4"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="5"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="6"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="7"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="8"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="9"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="10"></ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="11"></ColumnTotal>
</ColumnGroup>
</ColumnGroup>
</ColumnGroups>
<Cells>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>5</FormattedValue><Value>5.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>5</FormattedValue><Value>5.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>7</FormattedValue><Value>7.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>6</FormattedValue><Value>6.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>5</FormattedValue><Value>5.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="6">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>6</FormattedValue><Value>6.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="7">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>5</FormattedValue><Value>5.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="8">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>6</FormattedValue><Value>6.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="9">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>5</FormattedValue><Value>5.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="10">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>6</FormattedValue><Value>6.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="11">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>6</FormattedValue><Value>6.00</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
</Cells>
</CrossTab>
</Section>
</GroupFooter>
</Group>
<ReportFooter>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
</Section>
</ReportFooter>
</CrystalReport>
```

From it, I need to get the following:

```
Schedule Date - The date of the schedule itself
Part Number - from the Row Number
Week Due - from the Column Number
Quantity - from the row/column reference
PO Number - This will be auto generated from the week number
```

The table isn't created yet (but I can do that) and the file will always be stored in the same location. I intend to run an SQL job every day to check the table and any new values will be appended to it.

Could somebody please help me with the code to achieve this?

Comment: The XML you have there isn't valid, if you try parsing it into `xml` you get an error at line 316, specifically with the error `end tag does not match start tag`. if your XML isn't valid, it's very difficult to parse.

Comment: As @Larnu pointed out, please provide a well-formed XML.

Comment: There's actually more problems at the end too, `GroupFooter` is never closed at all. You have no hope of using SQL Server to process this, in honesty. You need to fix the data first.

Comment: @Larnu I had to edit the code to make it within the character limit and I must've cut out some code that I shouldn't have. I've cut out lines 11-52 but hopefully left it in a parseable state. Apologies for that.

Comment: Well, that parses now, good. What nodes are you after, you say "the Schedule date" for example, but there's no nodes called "schedule" or similar. "Part" doesn't even appear in the xml. Where is this data in the XML?

Comment: @Larnu The Part is the P number assigned to the RowNumber. 0 = P10711, 1 = P10822 etc. The 'Schedule date' is the DataDate on row 11 of the XML code. Thanks

Comment: @Larnu It is <RowGroups>
<RowGroup>
<RowGroup>
<RowTotal RowNumber="0">P10711</RowTotal>

Comment: Could it be that the format that they send it to us in, is not correct? I only have a very very limited knowledge of XML and the only other schedule I've seen is formatted very differently (it is formatted Part Number >>> Date >>> Quantity). This one appears to use variables for row and column numbers instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a blind stab in the dark, but with no expected results, then the best we can do. If this isn't right, hopefully it gets you on the right path:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail')
SELECT V.X,
       V.X.value('(/CrystalReport/Group/GroupHeader/Section[1]/Field/Value)[2]','date'),
       RG.RT.value('@RowNumber','varchar(10)') AS RowNumber,
       RG.RT.value('(text())[1]','varchar(10)') AS PartNumber,
       CG.CT.value('(text())[1]','varchar(10)') AS WeekDue
FROM(VALUES(@XML))V(X)
    CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/CrystalReport/Group/GroupFooter/Section[1]/CrossTab/RowGroups/RowGroup/RowGroup/RowTotal') RG(RT)
    CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/CrystalReport/Group/GroupFooter/Section[1]/CrossTab/ColumnGroups/ColumnGroup/ColumnGroup/ColumnTotal') CG(CT)
WHERE RG.RT.value('@RowNumber','varchar(10)') = CG.CT.value('@ColumnNumber','varchar(10)');
```

Comment: The expected results are based on the row/column references and the value associated to them. There is a node that references Row 3 Column 12 Value 10. Earlier up the document, row 3 is assigned to part P11236, column 12 is week 13 (0 is 1 etc.) so Part P11236 on week 13, 10 off parts are required. Row 4, Column 5, Value 40 equates to P12643, week 6, 40 off required. The schedule date for each of these is 10-02-2020. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @David I don't know your data, Yes i can see it, doesn't mean I understand it, the relationship in it or your expectations of it. You don't explains those things so I don't know them. This, however, hopefully will be enough to get you on the right path.